# Swift NSLocale Simulator iOS 8

Tags: xcode, swift, ios8, nslocale

I'm having an issue with Swift and the iOS 8 Emulator in XCode 6.1.

Indeed when I try to use NSLocale, almost every functions of it return nil.

Here is how I use it:

```
let cc = "fr" // Example
let locale = NSLocale.currentLocale()
let countryName = locale.displayNameForKey(NSLocaleCountryCode, value : cc)
println(countryName) // Shows : nil
```

It does work on device, iOS 7 and iOS 8 and on simulator iOS 7.
It doesn't work on simulator iOS 8 and on Playground, it even EXC_BAD_ACCESS.
I guess it's just a simulator and Playground problem, but it's weird still. And I wish to know if anyone has a workaround from it.

I did clean derived data, restarted and clean datas of simulator. Not getting better.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a known issue stated in the [release notes](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/releasenotes/DeveloperTools/RN-Xcode/Chapters/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001051-CH1-SW1) of Xcode 6.1:

> In some situations, [NSLocale currentLocale] may return en_US instead of the chosen locale in the iOS 8.1 simulator. (18512161

Comment: So the simulator is just bugged, not much to do but wait.

Comment: I also this issue on real devices with iOS 8.1.1