# xcode 6.1 iOS 8.1 NSLocale displayNameForKey NSLocaleIdentifier return nil

Tags: ios, objective-c, nslocale

```
- (NSString *)countryNameByCode:(NSString*)countryCode
{
    NSString *identifier = [NSLocale localeIdentifierFromComponents:@{NSLocaleCountryCode: countryCode}];
    NSString *countryName = [[NSLocale currentLocale] displayNameForKey:NSLocaleIdentifier value:identifier];

    return countryName;
}
```

This returned `nil`. Why?

Comment: It issue:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26603766/swift-nslocale-simulator-ios-8

Comment: This problem only simulator. I tested it on a device today, I get correct country Name.

Comment: just ran into this issue myself on the simulators - I populate a tableview with a list of all countries and in the simulator it just crashed due to displayNameForKey returning null. I have tried it on all simulator devices with 8.1 and they all crash. iPhone4 and iPhone 5 simulators with iOS 7.1 run fine. My code also runs fine on physical devices iPhone4s and iPhone5 with 8.1 installed so i'm guessing its just an Xcode bug. solution - until apple fix, test on device - which is a bugger as i don't have 6 and 6 plus to hand :(

Comment: possible duplicate of [NSLocale currentLocale always returns "en\_US" not user's current language](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1522210/nslocale-currentlocale-always-returns-en-us-not-users-current-language)

Answer (score 20):

This is a known Apple issue for iOS 8.1 *simulator* only - not reproducible on 8.1 devices. See below issue description from Xcode 6.1 release notes:

> Localization and Keyboard settings (including 3rd party keyboards) are
>   not correctly honored by Safari, Maps, and developer apps in the iOS
>   8.1 Simulator. **[NSLocale currentLocale] returns en_US** and only the English and Emoji keyboards are available. (18418630, 18512161).

See [Xcode 6.1 Release Notes](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/releasenotes/DeveloperTools/RN-Xcode/Chapters/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001051-CH1-SW1.) for more details.

Answer (score 7):

Please try below code, it should work. I tried it on my device as well as simulator 8.1

```
- (NSString *)countryNameByCode:(NSString*)countryCode {
  return [[NSLocale systemLocale] displayNameForKey:NSLocaleCountryCode value:countryCode];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This works for me

```
NSLocale *currentLocale = [[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:[NSLocale currentLocale].localeIdentifier];

 for (AVSpeechSynthesisVoice *voice in [AVSpeechSynthesisVoice speechVoices]) {
            NSString *languageLocalised = [currentLocale displayNameForKey:NSLocaleIdentifier value:voice.language];
            NSLog(@"%@ displayNameForKey %@: %@", currentLocale.localeIdentifier, voice.language, languageLocalised);
 }
```

Comment: Sidemark: Your first line contains redundant code. You could shorten it to NSLocale *currentLocale = [NSLocale currentLocale];

Answer (score 0):

```
- (NSString *)countryNameByCode:(NSString*)countryCode 
{
    NSString *identifier = [[NSLocale preferredLanguages] firstObject];
    NSLocale *locale = [[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:identifier];
    NSString *countryName = [locale displayNameForKey:NSLocaleIdentifier value:countryCode];
    return countryName;
}
```

I don't understand why `[[NSLocale currentLocale] displayNameForKey...]` doesn't return country name in `iOS 8` but the code above should resolve your problem.

Comment: Apparently that returns the language name (French, German...), not the country.

Comment: Yeh, not working on my end either... for country code "US", I get an identifier, "_US" which results in a country name, nil.

Comment: The solution is working, you just need to use `NSLocaleCountryCode` instead of `NSLocaleIdentifier`

Answer (score 0):

```
NSString *language = [[NSLocale preferredLanguages] objectAtIndex:0];
```